# react-native dependencies error: option '--entry-file' missing

Tags: react-native

**I am getting this error, whenever i try to check react-native dependencies**

**Given below is the output:-**

> D:.....\project_one>react-native dependencies
>
> error: option '--entry-file' missing
>
> Error: error: option '--entry-file' missing
>
> at options.forEach.opt
>   (D:....\project_one\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\util\assertRequiredOptions.js:30:13)
>   at Array.forEach ()
>
> at assertRequiredOptions
>   (D:....\project_one\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\util\assertRequiredOptions.js:19:11)
>
> at Promise.resolve.then
>   (D:.....\project_one\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cliEntry.js:116:7)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an `app.json` or `package.json` file? Try adding a line similar to this:

```
"entryPoint": "./src/app/index.js"
```

Except fill in your actual entry file instead

Comment: i am currently using both app.json or package.json file